# Recovering formulas for sequences with integer coefficients

Tags: integer-sequence

Suppose I know the sequence is of the $a n^4 + b n^3 +  c n^2 + d n$, with positive integers $a,b,c,d$, what is the easiest way to get them from the first few coefficients?

Here are the sequences I'm looking at. Mathematica's `FindSequenceFunction` works for the first one, but not for the rest

```
{15,48,105,192,315}
{15, 64, 183, 432, 895}
{15,80,273,720,1595}
{15, 144, 603, 1728, 3975}
```

Obtained from moments of Gaussian matrix products like $\operatorname{Tr}(AAAA^TA^TA^T)$ ([background](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818437/showing-e-operatornametraaatate-operatornametraataat-for-gaus))

```
Clear[a, A, n];
getMoment[n_, expr_] := (
   traceExpr = Tr[expr] /. A -> Array[a, {n, n}];
   distSpec = # \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1] & /@ 
     Variables[traceExpr];
   Expectation[traceExpr, distSpec]
   );
exprs = {A . A . A . A . A . A, 
   A\[Transpose] . A\[Transpose] . A . A\[Transpose] . A . A, 
   A . A . A . A\[Transpose] . A\[Transpose] . A\[Transpose], 
   A . A\[Transpose] . A . A\[Transpose] . A . A\[Transpose]};
getMomentSequence[expr_] := Table[getMoment[n, expr], {n, 1, 5}];
table = Table[
   With[{seq = getMomentSequence[expr]},
    {TraditionalForm@expr, TraditionalForm[seq], 
     Expand[FindSequenceFunction[seq][n]]}],
   {expr, exprs}];
TableForm[table]
```

Comment: `quarticCoeffs[ll_List /; Length[ll] == 5] := 
 Module[{x}, CoefficientList[InterpolatingPolynomial[ll, x], x]]` seems to work for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form` is the product `{ n^4, n^3, n^2, n} . {a, b, c, d}`

First we calculate matrix

```
m=Table[{ n^4, n^3, n^2, n},{n,1,5}];

abcd=Map[LinearSolve[m, #] &, seq]
(*{{0, 1, 6, 8}, {1, 0, 10, 4}, {2, 1, 8, 4}, {5, 6, 4, 0}}*)
```

check result

```
MapThread[0 == Norm[m . #2 - #1] &, {seq, abcd}]
(*{True, True, True, True}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
seq={{15,48,105,192,315},{15,64,183,432,895},{15,80,273,720,1595},{15,144,603,1728,3975}};

form=a n^4+b n^3+c n^2+d n;

form/.First@Solve[Table[form,{n,5}]==#]&/@seq
```

---

```
{8 n + 6 n^2 + n^3, 4 n + 10 n^2 + n^4, 4 n + 8 n^2 + n^3 + 2 n^4, 4 n^2 + 6 n^3 + 5 n^4}
```